# Splitting column into multiple columns every other delimiter in python

Tags: python

I have a column that I am trying to split into multiple columns in python. The data in the column looks like this below,

1;899.618000;2;0.551582;7;93.643914;8;12.00000

I need to split this column by every other delimiter (;) into separate columns, so I need it to look like the below.

Col1
1;899.618000

Comment: Are you using pandas? Or are we talking a list of list, i.e. a nested list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is consistently float-like, you can use a regex that checks if you have a non float representation after the separator:

```
s = '1;899.618000;2;0.551582;7;93.643914;8;12.00000'

import re
re.split(';(?=\d+;)', s)
```

output:

```
['1;899.618000', '2;0.551582', '7;93.643914', '8;12.00000']
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
s = "1;899.618000;2;0.551582;7;93.643914;8;12.00000"
l1 = s.split(";")
l2 = [l1[i]+l1[i+1] for i in range (0,len(l1),2)]
```

the value of l2 will be

```
['1899.618000', '20.551582', '793.643914', '812.00000']
```